# Swagger UI only produces raw HTML instead of landing page

Tags: javascript, json, swagger, swagger-ui

I'll try to provide as much information as I think might be relevant. I'm using NodeJS, MongoDB, .rest, and Render, though in this case I'm just trying to get things working locally first. Here are some of the files.

```
//swagger.js
const swaggerAutogen = require('swagger-autogen')();

const doc = {
  info: {
    title: 'My API',
    description: 'Welcome to my fumbling mess',
  },

  host: 'localhost:3000',
  schemes: ['http'],
};

const outputFile = './swagger-output.json';
const endpointsFiles = ['routes/index.js'];


swaggerAutogen(outputFile, endpointsFiles, doc);
```

```
//routes/index.js
const routes = require('express').Router();
routes.use('/characters', require('./characters'));
routes.use('/', require('./swagger-route'));
module.exports = routes;
```

```
//routes/swagger-route.js
const router = require('express').Router();
const swaggerUi = require('swagger-ui-express');
const swaggerDocument = require('../swagger-output.json');
router.use('/api-docs', swaggerUi.serve);
router.use('/api-docs', swaggerUi.setup(swaggerDocument));
module.exports = router;
```

```
//swagger.output.json

{
  "swagger": "2.0",
  "info": {
    "title": "My API",
    "description": "Welcome to my fumbling mess",
    "version": "1.0.0"
  },
  "host": "localhost:3000",
  "basePath": "/",
  "schemes": [
    "http"
  ],
  "paths": {
    "/characters/": {
      "get": {
        "description": "",
        "produces": [
          "application/json"
        ],
        "parameters": [],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "OK"
          },
          "500": {
            "description": "Internal Server Error"
          }
        }
      },
      "post": {
        "description": "",
        "parameters": [
          {
            "name": "body",
            "in": "body",
            "schema": {
              "type": "object",
              "properties": {
                "characterName": {
                  "example": "any"
                },
                "playerName": {
                  "example": "any"
                },
                "race": {
                  "example": "any"
                },
                "class": {
                  "example": "any"
                },
                "level": {
                  "example": "any"
                },
                "alignment": {
                  "example": "any"
                },
                "stats": {
                  "example": "any"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        ],
        "responses": {
          "201": {
            "description": "Created"
          },
          "400": {
            "description": "Bad Request"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "/characters/{id}": {
      "get": {
        "description": "",
        "produces": [
          "application/json"
        ],
        "parameters": [
          {
            "name": "id",
            "in": "path",
            "required": true,
            "type": "string"
          }
        ],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "OK"
          },
          "500": {
            "description": "Internal Server Error"
          }
        }
      },
      "put": {
        "description": "",
        "parameters": [
          {
            "name": "id",
            "in": "path",
            "required": true,
            "type": "string"
          },
          {
            "name": "body",
            "in": "body",
            "schema": {
              "type": "object",
              "properties": {
                "characterName": {
                  "example": "any"
                },
                "playerName": {
                  "example": "any"
                },
                "race": {
                  "example": "any"
                },
                "class": {
                  "example": "any"
                },
                "level": {
                  "example": "any"
                },
                "alignment": {
                  "example": "any"
                },
                "stats": {
                  "example": "any"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        ],
        "responses": {
          "204": {
            "description": "No Content"
          },
          "404": {
            "description": "Not Found"
          },
          "500": {
            "description": "Internal Server Error"
          }
        }
      },
      "delete": {
        "description": "",
        "parameters": [
          {
            "name": "id",
            "in": "path",
            "required": true,
            "type": "string"
          }
        ],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "OK"
          },
          "404": {
            "description": "Not Found"
          },
          "500": {
            "description": "Internal Server Error"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And finally, running http://localhost:3000/api-docs/ doesn't result in the actual frontend of the Swagger UI like it should. Instead I get this is raw html in the attached image.

Any ideas of what I could be doing wrong?

I tried in swagger-route.js to change the 5th line from router.get() to router.use()

I tried forgetting about localhost and changing the host paths to my Render web service but that just caused the same thing to happen on Render.

Comment: Read [those instructions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/swagger-ui-express#user-content-usage) carefully; you have `router.use` twice. The instructions have `router.use`, then `router.get`.

Comment: Here's an image of the raw HTML I'm looking at. https://imgur.com/gallery/TAtuPYd

Comment: An image of text is rarely helpful. [Please provide all relevant code, data, and errors as text, not images](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551).

Comment: Thank you for the idea, however I originally tried router.use then router.get with the same result.

Comment: Sounds like it's being served with a content-type header of text/plain instead of text/html. You can see for yourself by looking at the Network tab of your browser's developer tools.